# How do I split a vector to subvectors of varying lengths using R

Tags: r, split

I want to split a vector into subvectors of varying lengths by stating the mean lengts of the subvectors.

I am able to come across an answer that only gives a clue but not what I want at

```
ts <- 1:23 # the parent vector
bs <- 3 # lenght of subvector
nb <- length(ts) / bs # number of subvector
split(ts, rep(1:nb, each=bs, length.out = length(ts)))
#$`1`
#[1] 1 2 3

#$`2`
#[1] 4 5 6

#$`3`
#[1] 7 8 9

#$`4`
#[1] 10 11 12

#$`5`
#[1] 13 14 15

#$ `6`
#[1] 16 17 18

#$ `7`
#[1]
```

**what I want**

average length to be 4
variance length to be 2

**The nature of what I want**

```
#$`1`
#[1] 1 2 

#$`2`
#[1] 3 4 5 6

#$`3`
#[1] 7 8 9

#$`4`
#[1] 10 

#$`5`
#[1] 11 12 13 14 15 16

#$`6`
#[1] 17 18

#$`7`
#[1] 19 20 21 23 23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could create a normal distributed density vector `dens` with `length(ts)`, mean `4`, and variance `2`. From this we calculate probabilities `probs` that we use to draw random `sample()`s of length `ts`. From this we may sample `bins` with the desired lengths to `split()` `ts`. To make sure the bins actually have the desired mean and variance, we could pack the whole thing into a `repeat` loop until `all.equal()` with specific `tol` setting yields `TRUE`.

```
ts <- 1:23  # the parent vector
bs <- 3  # lenght of subvector
nb <- length(ts) / bs  # number of subvector


set.seed(69429)
repeat {
  dens <- dnorm(ts, mean=4, sd=sqrt(2))  # density
  probs <- dens/sum(dens)  # probabilities
  sizes <- sample(length(ts), size=nb, replace=TRUE, prob=probs)  # sample bin sizes
  bins <- as.numeric(sort(factor(
    sample(nb, length(ts), replace=TRUE),  # sample bins
    levels=1:length(ts))))
  if (all.equal(c(mean(table(bins)), var(table(bins))), c(4, 2), tol=.1) == TRUE) {
    break
  }
}
bins
# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 6 6 6 6
```

**Splitting**

```
(S <- split(ts, as.numeric(bins)))
# $`1`
# [1] 1 2 3 4
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 5 6 7 8
# 
# $`3`
# [1]  9 10 11 12 13 14
# 
# $`4`
# [1] 15 16 17
# 
# $`5`
# [1] 18 19
# 
# $`6`
# [1] 20 21 22 23
```

**Check**

```
c(mean=mean(lengths(S)), var=var(lengths(S)))
#     mean      var 
# 3.833333 1.766667
```

Comment: your code generates an error. `levels=1:length(s)` brought about the erorr. Do you mean `s` or `ts` or `bs`?